# Start/launch myApp when another app started/launched

Tags: android, android-intent, app-launcher

I am new to android. I want to know about..

I want to develop an app which start when another app(like gmail or facebook etc.) in the device started. I have no idea of how to develop this app. I want to support from API 21 & above

For older version of android below 8.0 i can use service and launch my app when specific app started (like applocker) But with higher version of android service is not allowed.

**And How i can start a service or any alternative class/component in android 8.0 and higher** when my app is not running(killed).
thanks.

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172468/12034846

Comment: thanks for the link , my main question is about running service or any alternative class/component in android 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Start service with thread and call below functionality with certain period of sleep time like one second in thread. This will start your app when other app runs in foreground

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningAppProcesses();
for (int currentProcess = 0; currentProcess < runningProcesses.size(); currentProcess++)
{
    if (runningProcesses.get(currentProcess).importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
    {
        if(!runningProcesses.get(currentProcess).pkgList[0].equalsIgnoreCase("your_app"))
        {
            //start your activity
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your partial answer, but how i can start a service in android 9.0 when my application is not running?